# Foreign key references while receiving attributes with the same name

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, entities

Example, I have this two entities:

**TICKET**

- Payment_ID (primary key)
- Amount

**BILL**

- Payment_ID (primary key)
- Amount

People can choose between this two payment methods, but this two entities have references in the **PAYMENT** entity, where I receive the primary key: **Payment ID**. But if I do this I can't make a the reference for Payment_ID:

**foreign key (Payment_ID) references TICKET(Payment_ID)**

Because, theres another Payment_ID that I have to reference to **BILL** in case I receive that one.

What can I do here? Just name the primary keys with another name and make them 'NULLS' in **PAYMENT**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

Instead of two tables have a single table with a code for the type.  (Combine Ticket and Bill and create a new column called type.)

The other way to solve this is to make a linking table.  Once again you have two choices:

```
PaymentDetail
-------------
PaymentID
TicketID
BillID
```

In this case you are joining your payment table to the other two tables and putting nulls in the one not being used.  (Note this assumes the two tables will have an ID column and not need a column for PaymentID since this table exists)

or

```
PaymentDetail
-------------
PaymentID
PaymentType
```

In this case you keep the columns you have and add in a type which can be one of BILL or TICKET.  The nice thing about this way is if you have more than one payment you just put in more rows in this table.

Comment: thanks for your help. I like the final option more. If I'm right, it will be something like this?

 ![Dropbox img](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zspm8ffvr5ntgmp/sql.png).

Comment: @SergioVera - that looks right, I'd draw the diagram with ticket and bill pointing to detail -- but that is a matter style I think.

Comment: thanks again for you answer. Is there any 'technical difference' if I point it to detail instead of Payment?.

Comment: @SergioVera - I'm not sure, not an expert on this kind of database model

Comment: Thanks. But what about when I have to reference the foreign key? Because I'm gonna receive two attributes with the same name from different tables. I can't do something like this, right?:

foreign key (Payment_ID) references BILL(Payment_ID),
foreign key (Payment_ID) references TICKET(Payment_ID)